# Import Google Calendar using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Does anyone know of a way to import Google Calendar entries into a database using SSIS.  I know I can export Calendars using the ICal format - but there is no native way to parse these files in SSIS.  The only way I can think of doing it is to write a script component to parse the file.  I'm wondering if anyone has any experience doing something like this what would be the best way to get the information.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/icalparser/ might be worth a look

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but hopefully it helps someone.  You can also export your calendar as xml.  Then you might be able to use SSIS with an XML source without the need to come up with script/ parser.  Good Luck.

References:
http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37648
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141093.aspx